# Extract two variables and rewrite multiple lines with sed

Tags: mysql, macos, sed

I have a massive query file with all sorts of use and update commands. I want to change the `update` to `insert...on duplicate key update`.

Sample query.sql file:

```
use database;

UPDATE table
SET value = '{"courseAuthor":"Company","courseCode":"ABCD1234"}'
WHERE id = 12;
```

I can just do find/replace on the `UPDATE table` so it becomes `INSERT INTO table (id, value)` but need to replace the next two lines so that they become:

```
VALUES( 12, '{"courseAuthor":"Company","courseCode":"ABCD1234"}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = '{"courseAuthor":"Company","courseCode":"ABCD1234"}';
```

My command is as follows

```
sed -Eni '' '/SET/ N; s|SET value = (.*) WHERE id = (.*);|VALUES (\2, \1)\\\nON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = \1;|g' query.sql
```

My problem is when I run this on MacOS, the query.sql file is completely wiped out. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are the columns in question always `id` (with an `=`) and `value` (as target)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple problems in the `sed` script. You've used `-n` to suppress automatic printing, but there is no instruction to print anything in the `sed` script, so it resulted in no output. And using `-i` for in-place editing just vacuumed your file. You need to add `p` for print.

It also did not match anything, because you've read second line of input into pattern space, but tried to match space where there is a newline. I've replaced  with `\n` and got, either:

```
/SET/{N; s|SET value = (.*)\nWHERE id = (.*);|VALUES (\2, \1)\nON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = \1;|p}
```

or:

```
/SET/{N; s|SET value = (.*)\nWHERE id = (.*);|VALUES (\2, \1)\nON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = \1;|;p}
```

The difference between the two is. Former prints (only) after successful substitution. Latter even if the line did not get changed. Which would make it probably easier to spot if a line with `SET` that should have matched did not. Admittedly the regex does look a little fragile, but hopefully the inputs format is strict enough.